# Differential equation including Dirac Delta function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I am trying to understand Dirac delta function. Here is a DE to solve:
$f''(x) - 3f'(x) +2f(x)=k\delta(x-a)$ with intial conditions $ f(0)=f'(0)=1$ where $ k \in \mathbb{R}$ is constant.

I know this is dead easy to solve with Laplace transform, but how can I do it directly?

Just need a hint, a starting point...

Comment: Solve the ODE for $x<a$ and for $x>a$ (the delta is zero in these regimes). Then do a matching at $x=a$ to determine the unknown constants in your solution. To derive one of the matching conditions you can integrate the ODE over $[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$ and take $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: @Winther I think the last bit is where my trouble is - how can I integrate the ODE? f'' and f' are not a problem, how do I handle f?

Comment: Note that $f$ has to be continuous at $x=a$ so $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} f(x){\rm d}x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You know the eigenvalues are 1 and 2, thus consider $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$ with
$$
g'-g=e^{-x}(f'(x)-2f(x)),\\---\\
g''-g'=e^{-x}(f''(x)-3f'(x)+2f(x))=e^{-x}·kδ(x−a)=e^{-a}·kδ(x−a)
$$
This can be integrated once, and using the Heaviside function as the integral of delta,
$$
g'-g=ke^{-a}·H(x-a)+C
$$
Substituting again $h(x)=e^{-x}g(x)$ results in
$$
h'(x)=e^{-x}(g'-g)=ke^{-a-x}·H(x-a)+C·e^{-x}
$$
with integral
$$
h(x)=k(e^{-2a}-e^{-a-x})H(x-a)-C·e^{-x}+D
\\
\implies
\\
f(x)=e^{2x}·h(x)=k(e^{2(x-a)}-e^{x-a})H(x-a)-C·e^x+D·e^{2x}
$$

By playing around with the constant, this can be changed into
$$
f(x)=\frac k2·\left|e^{2(x-a)}-e^{x-a}\right|+c·e^x+de^{2x}
$$